# `unpack('Q', ...) % (1 << 62)` resulting in negative value with `use integer` on x86_64

Tags: perl, 64-bit, modulo, unpack

Testing a random number function I wrote in the debugger I'm getting unexpected results.
Specifically for `use integer` the result of `unpack('Q', random_bytes(...)) % (1 << 62)` seems to be negative.

Here's a part of the debugger session:

```perl
  DB<3> x Random::random_number(0, 1 << 62)
Random::random_number(lib/Random.pm:95):
95:             $result = unpack('Q', random_bytes($type, 8)) % $limit;
  DB<<4>> x $limit
0  4611686018427387904
  DB<<5>> c

  DB<5> x Random::random_number(0, 1 << 62)
Random::random_number(lib/Random.pm:95):
95:             $result = unpack('Q', random_bytes($type, 8)) % $limit;
  DB<<6>> c
0  '-2479142448669864359'
```

The first parameter (`$type`) specified the random generator to use in `random_bytes()`, while the second parameter specified how many bytes to return.

So I wonder:
If `unpack('Q', ...)` returns an unsigned 64 bit number and `$limit` is positive, how can the result of `%` be negative?

Happened in Perl 5.18.2 on x86_64.

### More details

As requested I'll provide more details; see this extract of a debugger session:

```perl
  DB<1> p Random::random_number(0, 1 << 62)
b=a7466b82e166e3cd
q=14835814716230289063, l=4611686018427387904
-3610929357479262553
  DB<2> p Random::random_number(0, 1 << 62)
b=411be7e0f74f97e1
q=16255549306065853249, l=4611686018427387904
-2191194767643698367
  DB<3> p Random::random_number(0, 1 << 62)
b=43d07134e528df37
q=4025981556785008707, l=4611686018427387904
4025981556785008707
```

`b` are the bytes in hex (`unpack('H*', ...)`), `q` is the quad (64-bit), `l` is the limit.

Surprisingly, when I do the calculation in the debugger, the result is not negative:

```perl
  DB<5> p 4025981556785008707 % 4611686018427387904
4025981556785008707
  DB<6> p 16255549306065853249 % 4611686018427387904
2420491250783689537
```

Comment: Cam you show the value returned by `random_bytes($type, 8)`?

Comment: @choroba Will do, hacked the code to provide extra output.

Comment: Can you explain why you are doing `use integer;`?  That's too heavy a hammer to use for most purposes.

Comment: I was using integer as I expected not to need floating point inside the code block, expecting the code to be a bit more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

As documented, [integer](http://p3rl.org/integer) will truncate all operands to math operations (`%` here) to the integer range `-(2**63) .. (2**63-1)`.
Actually it says:

> Normally, the operands and results are treated as **unsigned** integers, but with `use integer`; the operands and results are **signed**. This means, among other things, that ~0 is -1 *(...)*

The result of the `unpack 'Q'` might be outside that range.

```perl
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

my $code = << '__CODE__';
my $x = unpack Q => "\xff" x 8;
my $r = $x % 2;  # You can use $x * 1, too.
say for $x, $r;
__CODE__

eval $code;

use integer;
eval $code;
```

Output:

```
18446744073709551615
1
18446744073709551615
-1
```

The reason why the result in the debugger is different is because the `use integer` is lexical, i.e. it doesn't propage to the debugger context.

Comment: So basically the answer is: "While `unpack 'Q'` interprets the data as unsigned, there are *no unsigned integers* in Perl actually"? Unfortunately the difference only occurs for numbers where the highest bit is set (which isn't very likely for 64-bit numbers).

Comment: @U.Windl, Perl does have unsigned ints  And `unpack Q` returns one as seen in the answer. `use integer` causes `%` to cast the inputs to signed ints.

Comment: @U.Windl: See the update to answer your additional question.

Comment: @ikegami I doubt it: Aren't the numbers without `use integer` just floating point (displayed as integer)?

Comment: @U. Windl, No. IV (signed ints), UV (unsigned ints) or NV (floating point numbers)